# Access C# method in DLL from Java

Tags: java, c#, dll, dllimport

I'm having trouble trying to call a function writed in C# from Java. I have already loaded the dll that contains the function.

Error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: app.clsValidation.validate(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

C# code compiled into a 64-bit dll:

```
namespace library {

    public class clsValidation {

        public string validate(string txt) {
            return txt;
        }
    }
}
```

**Java code**

The class:

```
package app;

public class clsValidation {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("library");
    }

    public native String validate(String txt);
}
```

How I'm calling it in Java:

```
String txt = "something";
String result = new clsValidation().validate(txt);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's to be expected. Your Java code treats the C# DLL as if it were an unmanaged library. It is not. It does not export unmanaged functions that can be imported using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

If you wish to export unmanaged functions from your .net DLL then you can:

1. Use Robert Giesecke's UnamanagedExports to do so.
2. Make a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly which exports unmanaged functions.

Other options would include exposing the functionality through COM which is readily consume from Java.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me! Now I know what to look for.

Comment: What do you mean by COM ?

Comment: Try a websearch. I could do that, but I think you could too.

Comment: I just want the meaning of COM... I don't get anything googling 'COM java'. Thanks.

Comment: Google COM on its own. It's an MS tech.